# Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) drops connection to https site with self signed certificate

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https, internet-explorer-9, self-signed

I have an internal (intranet) site which has https via self-signed certificate.
It works fine in Google Chrome, but when I try to open it in IE9, Internet Explorer 9 just drops the connection and shows the error "Internet Explorer cannot display the page".

If I try to monitor network via Browser Developer tools I see that connection was just dropped by IE like here.

[image]

I already tried trusted sites, compatibility mode, clean cookies, caches, reset settings, different ssl options in advanced settings but nothing help.

Also, I have to use IE9, because there are some dependencies from some applications, which I cannot avoid.

Maybe it is a well know problem and there is a solution?

UPDATE:
It was fixed by deleting one of the windows updates. One of the updates broke IE9 :) Maybe now it is not the case anymore but if someone will have a similar issue in the future, check recently installed updates and try to remove them.

Comment: IE9 is unsupported. You should be using IE11 and Enterprise Site mode lists to manage backward compatibility of legacy intranet applications. Open in IE11, then f12>Emulation tab, confirm that the domain is mapped to the expected emulation mode of IE9. Depending on network configuration, localhost can be mapped to the IE Internet zone (default). Use the File>Properties menu in IE to determine which IE zone it is mapped to.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this approach. I did not think about this one.